# How to test whether file at path exists in repo?

Tags: perforce

Given a path (on my computer), how can I test whether that file is under version control (ie. a copy exists in the Perforce depot)? I'd like to test this at the command line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check `p4 help files`.  In short, you run `p4 files <your path here>` and it will give you the depot path to that file.  If it isn't in the depot, you'll get "no such file(s)".

Comment: Thanks Mark. Any idea how to read the latest docs online? I can only find 12.1 http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/help.html

Comment: The current docs are always available at http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide

Comment: Hum the page on the diff command has disappeared http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/diff.html

Comment: Here it is: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/#p4_diff.html

I guess I should have pointed you at http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref instead.

Comment: I thought about that too, but the problem with `p4 where` is that it will also tell you where a file WOULD be mapped if it existed.  For example, if you are mapping `//depot/project/...` to a root of `C:\project` and you do a `p4 where C:\project\thisfiledoesnotexist.txt` it will still give you `//depot/project/thisfiledoesnotexist.txt //myclient/project/thisfiledoesnotexist.txt C:\project\thisfiledoesnotexist.txt` which isn't as helpful as I wish it were. :-)

Comment: Note for scripting that **this always exits with the same value**; you'll have to run something like `p4 files FILE | grep ^//` to get a proper exit code, and then your code is subjected to potential formatting changes in future perforce releases.

Answer (score 3):

For scripting, [`p4 files FILE`](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_files.html) is insufficient because it doesn't change its exit code when there is no such file.

Instead, you can pass it through grep, which looks for perforce paths' telltale pair of leading slashes:

```bash
# silently true when the file exists or false when it does not.
p4_exists() { 
  p4 files -e "$1" 2>/dev/null |grep -q ^//
}
```

You can get rid of the `2>/dev/null` and grep's `-q` if you want visible output.

Before [p4 files version 2012.1](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/files.html) (say [p4 files version 2011.1](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r11.1/manuals/cmdref/files.html)), it didn't support `-e`. You'll have to add `|grep -v ' - delete [^-]*$'` before the grep above.

> [image: ⚠] **Warning**: A future `p4` release could change the formatting and break this logic.

Comment: instead of a file how do we test the repo folder path is valid or not ?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz – great question, but I don't have an easy answer. I suggest asking it in a new SO question. Provide a link to this question as background information.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Adam Katz's solution except more likely to be supported by future releases of `p4`, you can pass [global option `-s`](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v15.1/cmdref/global.options.html) which 'prepends a descriptive field' to each line. This is one of 'text', 'info', 'error' or 'exit' followed by a colon (and a space, it seems). This is intended for facilitating scripting.

For all files passed in to the `p4 -s files` command, you should get one line back per file. If the file exists in the depot, the line starts with `info:` whereas if the file does not exist in the depot, the line starts with `error:`. For example:

```
info: //depot/<depot-path-to-file>
error: <local-path-to-file>
```

So, essentially, the status lines are the equivalent of an exit code but on a per-file basis. An exit code alone wouldn't cope neatly with an arbitrary number of files passed in.

Note that if there is a different error (e.g. a connection error) then an error line is still output. So, if you really want the processing to be robust, you may want to combine this with what Adam Katz suggested or perhaps grep for the basename of the file in the output line.